# For loop resets after an exception

Tags: java, exception

Currently, I'm working on a Multiple Choice Quiz. But I'm stuck with this problem. After an exception, my for loop resets and basically returns to 0. Is there any other way to solve this? Or is my code logically wrong? Whenever a exception is thrown, the for loop resets. 
For example, I'm on question number 5 and an exception occurred, the for loop goes back to 0.

```
do{

  try {

  Scanner A = new Scanner (System.in);

  for (int x = 0; x < Questions.length;x++){

      loop = x;
      System.out.println(Questions[x]);
      System.out.println(Choices[x]);

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.print("Answer: ");

      UAnswer = A.nextLine();


      if (UAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("A") || UAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("B") || UAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){

          if (UAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(AnswerKey[x])){
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("Correct Answer!\n");
          Score++;
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println("Wrong! The correct answer is: " + AnswerKey[x] + "\n");

          }

      }
      else if (UAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
          throw new NullPointerException();
        }
      else {
          throw new InputMismatchException(); 
        }

      }
  }
  catch(InputMismatchException ime){
  System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Invalid input! Please type A,B,C!\n");

      }


  catch(NullPointerException b){
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("You did not input any answer.\n");

      }

    }while(loop != 9);
```

Comment: Where's your `catch`?  If you're handling the exception outside the loop then you'll be outside the loop when you handle the exception.

Comment: What do you mean with "the for loop resets"? You simply break out of the loop in case of an exception.

Comment: Why throw those exceptions? Just move the error handling code into the `else if` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you throw your exception, you go back to the beginning of your do while loop because that's where your try block starts.  If you don't want to reset your loop in an exception, put a try catch block within your for loop.